# in a json file I'm getting illegal escape sequence

Tags: json

When I try to have in a json file this:

```
"pattern": "^carbon\..*",
```

I'm getting the error
Illegal escape sequence.
How should I write the json, please?

Thank you.
Gabriel

Comment: What is the output you expect? If you expect `^carbon\..*` than you should use double backslashes `^carbon\\..*`

Comment: What is the exact string you are trying to represent?

Answer (score 6):

The problem is \. is not a recognised escape sequence. If you want a \ in your string you will need to enter \\.